# How I can enable Folder/directory upload in a Angular 6

Tags: angular, file-upload, dropzone

As of now I am using Ngx-dropzone-Wrapper plugin for uploading the files.

But now i want to add folder selector in Dropzone plugin.

So is there any way to add dropzone folder select option with webkitdirectory api or with different way.

And if no So any other alternative of dropzone which support folder upload + having chunking option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can share with you my own solution.

First of all, I don't use third party libraries, sso let's start with a simple drag-drop directive.

```html
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUploadDragAndDrop]',
})
export class UploadDragAndDropDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private r2: Renderer2, private uploadSbService: UploadSnackbarService) {}

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  @HostListener('dragenter', ['$event']) onDragEnter(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    this.r2.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'upload-blackout');
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) onDragLeave(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    this.r2.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'upload-blackout');
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) onDrop(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    const files = e.dataTransfer?.files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      console.log(Array.from(files));
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can drop the files, but what if we want to work with the folder as well?
We shoud apply this [method(webkitGetAsEntry)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry) to our solution.

And we will get somethink like:

```html
export class UploadDragAndDropDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private r2: Renderer2, private uploadSbService: UploadSnackbarService) {}

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  @HostListener('dragenter', ['$event']) onDragEnter(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    this.r2.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'upload-blackout');
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) onDragLeave(e: DragEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    this.r2.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'upload-blackout');
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) onDrop(e: any): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();


    const items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    this.getFilesDataTransferItems(items).subscribe(array => console.log(this.flatten(array)));
  }

  private flatten(arr: any[]): [] {
    return arr.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => (flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? this.flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten)), []);
  }

  private getFilesDataTransferItems(dataTransferItems: DataTransferItemList): Observable<unknown[]> {
    const traverseFileTreePromise =
      (item: any, path: string | null = ''): Observable<unknown> => new Observable<unknown>(resolve => {
        if (item.isFile) {
          item.file((file: File) => {
            resolve.next(file);
          });
        } else if (item.isDirectory) {
          const dirReader = item.createReader();
          dirReader.readEntries((entries: any[]) => {
            const entriesPromises = [];
            for (const entr of entries)
              {entriesPromises.push(
                traverseFileTreePromise(entr, path || ''  + item.name + '/')
              );}
            zip(entriesPromises).pipe(tap((data) => resolve.next(data))).subscribe();
          });
        }
      });

    return new Observable(resolve => {
      const entriesPromises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < dataTransferItems.length; i++) {
        const fileEntry = dataTransferItems[i].webkitGetAsEntry();

        if (fileEntry) {
          entriesPromises.push(traverseFileTreePromise(fileEntry, null));
        }
      }
      zip(entriesPromises).pipe(tap((data) => resolve.next(data))).subscribe();
    });
  }
}
```